# Javascript array length not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this array:

```
[first_name: false, last_name: false, email: false, month: false, day: false, year: false, password: false, password2: false]
```

Now I if I do this `console.log(arrayName.length)` it will return 0; why? What I'm doing wrong?

//LE

This is how I do it:

```
var errors = {};
 $('.register-front').delegate('button','click',function(){
  var $this = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
  $this.find('input,select').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val() || ($(this).val() == '-1'))
    {
      errors[$(this).attr('name')] = false;
    }
  });
  console.log(errors.length);
  return false;
 });
```

I made some changes but I still don't get it....

Comment: That's the structure of an object, not an array.

Comment: There are no associative arrays in JS. You should use an object (map) instead.

Comment: Use `var errors = {};` to initialize your associative array (a.k.a. "plain object" in JavaScript lingo).

Comment: See my updated answer. You can use `Object.keys(errors).length` instead of `errors.length`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your notation seems odd. The square brackets are for an array, but the contents are object attribute/value notation. I don't think that will work. You can turn your expression into an object by replacing the `[]` with `{}`, but then, objects don't have length. You can get the number of keys in an object with:

```
Object.keys(obj).length
```

Alternatively, you can iterate through the object keys with:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    . . .
}
```

**EDIT** For the specific code you added, you can replace this line:

```
console.log(errors.length);
```

with:

```
console.log(Object.keys(errors).length);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, assotiative-array-like structure is Object:

```
{
    lorem: 'ipsum',
    dolor: 'amet'
}
```

In your example, replace square brackets with curly brackets, and you'll get such object.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't an `Array`, an `Array` is a simple list of values where as this is a mapping of keys to values, i.e. an `Object`. You mean to do something like:

```
var myObject = { first_name: false, last_name: false, email: false, month: false, day: false, year: false, password: false, password2: false }
```